# Make a flate table in php

Tags: php, mysql

There is a problem with table, why the field's row repeat in all register?

Here is the code;

```
<?php

----
-------
-------

$result=mysqli_query($dbcon,$consult);



while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
echo "<table><tr><th>NIF</th><th>Name</th><th>lastname</th> <th>Edad</th></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>";
echo $row[0]."</td><td>";
echo $row[1]."</td><td>";
echo $row[2]."</td><td>";
echo $row[3]."</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

?>
```

Comment: *"Make a flate table in php"* - What do you mean by that? I don't understand. "Flate" isn't a word I heard of before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the field rows out side of the loop

```
<?php

// DB Query
$result=mysqli_query($dbcon,$consult); $i=0;

// Starting the table
print ("
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>NIF</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>lastname</th> 
        <th>Edad</th>
    </tr>");

    // Result loop
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
        // Table content
        print ("
        <tr>
            <td>".$row[0]."</td>
            <td>".$row[1]."</td>
            <td>".$row[2]."</td>
            <td>".$row[3]."</td>
        </tr>");
    $i++;
    }

    // No results
    if ($i==0){
        print ("
        <tr>
            <td colspan='4'>No results</td>
        </tr>");
    }

// Closing table
print ("</table>");

?>
```